# MATLAB: changes in vector elements

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a some vectors of different large sizes and their value is between `0` and `1`. I want to save those indices of elements which there would be any changes in decimal. For an small example, let's assume

```
     V=[0.02,0.1,0.4,0.0054,0.05];
```

Now the ouptput for this should be as

```
     i={2,4,5}
```

Would you please let me know how it can be done?

Comment: Maybe when you use `find(diff(floor(log10(V))) ~= 0)+1`, the output is sufficient for you.

Comment: @Nemesis Make that an answer. And you can remove `~=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Luis Mendo (including his suggestion with removing **~= 0**), here the comment as answer. You can use the logarithm function to determine your number of decimals for you.

```
i = find(diff(floor(log10(V))))+1
```

Be sure to use **floor** to have integer values you can compare to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = arrayfun(@(x) regexp(num2str(x),'\.','split'),V, 'UniformOutput', false)
dp = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) length(x{2}),count, 'UniformOutput', false))
find(diff(dp))+1
```

I did it this way. First I split the numbers and next i find the length of the second term and lastly, I find whether the length is different from its previous..